# ValueError: time data ' 02/20/18' does not match format '%m/%d/%y'

Tags: python, datetime

I understand this is a common error but my brain does not understand why I keep having this issue. I've switch around the formatting placement references multiple times but I still receive an error when the program is ran. Help me understand why this error is happening.

```
event_date = datetime.strptime(current_event[1], '%m/%d/%y').date()
```

File Data :
Halloween,10/31/17
Spanish Test,12/01/17
School Trip, 02/20/18
Birthday Day,01/11/18

Comment: Note the leading space. `'02/20/18'` and `' 02/20/18'` are different strings.

Comment: The [mre] is `datetime.strptime(' 02/20/18', '%m/%d/%y')` - `datetime.strptime('02/20/18', '%m/%d/%y')` works just fine.

Comment: Found the issue, Thanks!